# Why integration by substitution?

Tags: integration

Suppose that $g$ is a continous function in the interval $[a,b]$ and $c$ is a constant.

I have to show that.

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=(1/c)\int_{ca}^{cb}f(x/c)dx$

My first idea was to do the following:

$(1/c)\int_{ca}^{cb}f(x/c)dx=(1/c)[F(x/c)]_{ca}^{cb}=(1/c)[F(b)-F(a)]\neq\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$

But since this did not work I use integration by substitution setting $u=x/c\Rightarrow dx=cdu$

$(1/c)\int_{ca}^{cb}f(x/c)dx=(1/c)\int^{b}_{a}f(u)cdu=\int^{b}_{a}f(u)du=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$

I hope someone can explain why the former method does not work and the latter method does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say
$$
(1/c)\int_{ca}^{cb}f(x/c)dx=(1/c)[F(x/c)]_{ca}^{cb}
$$
then you're using the fundamental theorem of calculus, which in this case takes the (simplified) form

> If $G'(x) = g(x)$ for functions $g, G$, then $\int_s^tg(x)\,dx = [G(x)]_s^t$.

Except that if $g(x) = f(x/c)$, and $G(x) = F(x/c)$ (which is what you have used), then we don't have $G'(x) = g(x)$. So you're not following the theorem. It should be $G(x) = cF(x/c)$. So what you actually have is
$$
(1/c)\int_{ca}^{cb}f(x/c)dx=(1/c)[cF(x/c)]_{ca}^{cb}
$$
and from there you can do the same manipulations as you did and actually get $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$ at the other end.